# Node.js: How to call method with callback in a cycle?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to call method with callback in cycle?

Suppose I need to call `http.get` but be sure that only one request is awaiting response in a time (that is not putting too much presser on a server)

```
http.get(url, function(res) {
  console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

Comment: Use [async.waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall). I hope this helps you out.

Comment: Looks like you need a full blown http-request client+manager similar to Volley for Android. It really does not exist in JS world but I think you should take a look at Wrek - https://github.com/hapijs/wreck . One thing you can easily try is - create a singleton http-client with a queue for requests ( and callbacks ) and make it so that it processes the requests one by one. It won't be perfect... but will still work.

Comment: You can use [q promises module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/q), and if request is sent, but not finished, you collect next requested promises to the array (e.g. queue[]), and on resolve() of current request, run Q.all(queue), and while it resolves you collect new array of queries, and on its resolve run Q.all(queue) for new collected queries. But if you never worked with queries it might be pretty complicated. And usually servers designed to handle way more queries then one in a time. It looks like really weird case.

Answer (score 2):

> You can try this recurcive call, which takes how many requests to
>   handle. make sure you declare count as global variable.

```
var count = 0;

function cyclicCall(numberOfRequests, callback) 
{

    http.get(url, function (res) {
        count++;
        if (numberOfRequests != count) {
            console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
            cyclicCall(count, callback)
        }
        else {
            callback();
        }

    }).on('error', function (e) {
        console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) and user after.

```
var _ = require('underscore');
var call = _.after(N, callback);

for(var i = 0; i < N; i++){
 http.get(url, function(res) {
  console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
  call();
 }).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
  call();
 });
}
```